# A solution to increase my EMR master node capacity without shutting down the cluster

Tags: amazon-emr

My EMR master node has become full and I need to attach some ESB volumne to it, is there any way to do it without terminating the cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add additional EBS volumes & also resize

How to explained here :

https://superuser.com/questions/1409373/how-to-add-an-ebs-volume-by-snapshot-id-to-amazon-emr

https://github.com/qyjohn/AWS_Tutorials/wiki/Grow-EBS-volumes-on-EMR-clusters

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. This is because you set up Amazon Elastic Block Store (Amazon EBS) volumes and configure mount points when the cluster is launched, so it’s difficult to modify the storage capacity after the cluster is running.

> The feasible solutions usually involve adding more nodes to your
>   cluster, backing up your data to a data lake, and then launching a new
>   cluster with a higher storage capacity. Or, if the data that occupies
>   the storage is expendable, removing the excess data is usually the way
>   to go.

For more details,have a look at: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/dynamically-scale-up-storage-on-amazon-emr-clusters/